# could not create unique index "credits_credit_pkey"

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Initially, I had a model of `Credit`. But after adding models of `Hypothec` and `AutoCredit` with similar functionality, I realized that I needed to make a base model and inherit from it.

When I tried makemigrations, I received a question:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'abstractbaseproduct_ptr' to `credit` without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

*I entered 1; 1. Then I got this question:

> It is not clear what the 'abstractbaseproduct_ptr' field is?

Then i got

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field abstractbaseaction_ptr to creditaction without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

**Again introduced 1; 1.**

When I try to migrate, I get

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "credits_credit_pkey"
>   DETAIL: Key (abstractbaseproduct_ptr_id) = (1) is duplicated.

Such questions arose only with the `Credit` model. Apparently, because there is `already data in this table`...

How should I fix this?

```
class AbstractBaseProduct(models.Model):
    bank = models.ForeignKey('banks.Bank', verbose_name=_('bank'))
    #other fields


class AbstractBaseAction(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    short_description = models.CharField(_('short description'), max_length=255)
    full_description = models.TextField(_('full description'), blank=True, null=True)


class Credit(AbstractBaseProduct):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('credit')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Credits')


class CreditAction(AbstractBaseAction):
    credit = models.ForeignKey(Credit, verbose_name=_('credit'))
```

**migration**

```
migrations.AddField(
            model_name='credit',
            name='abstractbaseproduct_ptr',
            field=models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, default=1, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='credits.AbstractBaseProduct'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
migrations.AddField(
            model_name='creditaction',
            name='abstractbaseaction_ptr',
            field=models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, default=1, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='credits.AbstractBaseAction'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
```

Comment: set `default=1` for this column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 1.7: Makemigration: non-nullable field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012340/django-1-7-makemigration-non-nullable-field)

Comment: @shafik for which column?

Comment: @bdoubleu don't work

Comment: `abstractbaseproduct_ptr_id` for which column you got some confirmation message when run `makemigrations`

Comment: @shafik I posted you the whole question. Added another code with the migration.

Comment: @Alasdair very thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your model `AbstractBaseProduct`, but you haven't added `abstract = True` to the model's `Meta` class, so Django thinks you want multi-table inheritance instead of abstract base classes.

See the docs on [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) for more info.